# Water spots on drywall

Tags: ceiling, drywall-mud

I have water and mildew damage on my ceiling. The ceiling is drywall. What’s the best method of repair for this situation?

Comment: Find and fix the leak.  Roof or water pipes.  After leak is fix, there are are number of paints/primers to hide/cover stains.  If leak has been happening for a long time might need to replace sheetrock/drywall.

Comment: If the sheetrock is damaged, then replacement is only option, but can probably find the leak easier once it is removed(roof leaks can be difficult to find).

Comment: @crip659 Please make your answer into an Answer, it should not be a comment.